# Container with xyz key

Tags: java, containers

I need a **fast** container to store objects in Java, the objects have (static) XYZ coordinates and all the objects have different coordinates. Basically a grid, but it might not be centered around 0,0,0 (and there might be missing parts in the grid).

I tried using a Map with a Integer as key and bit-shifting the coordinates so it would create a unique number for every coordinate. But this didn't work out too well when the numbers were higher then 255 (8 bits).

Also arrays don't work as key, since maps don't actually look at the value of the array, but at the reference. I could also use a String as key, but then everytime I want to access an object, I will need to (re)build a String.

Now I am using a ArrayList and looping through all the keys, but that is really slow. So what would be the fastest (and memory-efficient) way to store the objects?

Comment: You're looping through to get something? What is that?

Comment: Your x, y, and z cannot be different all the object, since they are static.

Comment: @BheshGurung What? The object's xyz values don't change. But all the objects do have different values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a custom class, with a custom hashCode() and equals() method to use as the key.

```
public static class Vertex {
    public int x, y, z;
    public boolean equals(Object o){
        if(this == o) return true;
        if(!(o instanceof Vertex)) return false;
        Vertex v = (Vertex)o;
        return x == v.x && y == v.y && z == v.z;
    }

    public int hashCode(){
        //  Use whatever prime numbers you like
        return x ^ y * 137 ^ z * 11317;
    }
}
```

Just make sure you never, ever change the values of an instance that you're using as a key.

This isn't significantly worse than using simple integers. It's still effectively constant-time access.

Comment: I actually tried this, but I had trouble making the hashCode method. I did something like `x<<16 | y<<8 | z<<0`. That gave errors with high numbers though. What is the magic behind the prime numbers? Do you mind explaining/giving a link?

Comment: The purpose is because of the way the hashmap stores values. It usually has an even-numbered number of buckets (because it doubles the capacity when it needs to expand), and in order to figure out where to store an entry, it will modulus the hashcode by the number of buckets. If you are multiplying either of the coordinates by anything that shares a prime factor with the number of buckets, things lying along the same axis or plane will end up in the same bucket, which at worst turns the map into a list with O(n) access rather than O(1).

Comment: It's a rather large subject by itself. Look up hash tables, hashing functions and collisons.

Comment: Also, using the xor operator (^) is a lot better than bitwise or (|) for the same reasons.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I kind of understand it now. I will do some further research on the things you said.

Comment: I don't know why you were getting errors, though. But that's better left to a separate question.

Comment: I wasn't really getting errors in the form of exceptions, but for example y=128,x=0 and y=127,x=1 (if z is the same) would give the same key.

Comment: Yeah, that would be the same key. Because 1 << 16 == 128 << 8. Because you were using an OR the y value was hiding the x value. That's exactly why I recommended using xor. You could do addition instead, but I personally think xor works out better.